# MVC get dropdownlist selected value to TempData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using an MVC model and i want to save the selected value from a dropdownlist.

here is what i have so Far

Model.

```
namespace FormsAuthenticationMVC.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Report_Security
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> UserName_ID { get; set; }
        public string ReportName { get; set; }
        public string Report_Url { get; set; }
        public string EmbedCode { get; set; }

        public List<Report_Security> ReportList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using FormsAuthenticationMVC.Models;

namespace FormsAuthenticationMVC.Controllers
{

    //[Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {    
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Reports()
        {   
            // this is working fine. the dropdown is populated from the model correctly.

            ViewBag.Message = "O2 Dashboard";

            ASP_AuthEntities ReportTable = new ASP_AuthEntities();

            var getReportTable = ReportTable.Report_Security.ToList();
            SelectList list = new SelectList(getReportTable, "EmbedCode", "ReportName");
            ViewBag.ReportListName = list;

            return View();
    }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Reports(Report_Security model, string Code)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)

                TempData["HtmlSelected"] = Code;  // = This is where i shall set the dropdown value

            return View(model);        
        }              
    }
}
```

and my view

```
@model FormsAuthenticationMVC.Models.Report_Security     
@{    
    <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(r =>r.EmbedCode, new SelectList(Model.EmbedCode,"EmbedCode"),"Select Report")       
<h5>@TempData["HtmlSelected"]</h5>   @*----- SELECTED DROPDOWN VALUE*@
```

When i run debug and i put a breakpoint in my view at the @Html.DropDownListFor ...... line i get the following error.

System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model.get returned null.

Could someone help me out please.

Comment: You are doing `ViewBag.ReportListName = list;` but not using it in view. You have `ReportList` property in the model class but you are not using it anywhere.

Comment: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-dropdownlist-dropdownlistfor

Comment: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/asp-net-mvc-populating-dropdown-lists-in-razor-views-using-the-mvvm-design-pattern-entity-framework-and-ajax